# How to get published content from Umbraco API controller ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco

I am storing some email templates(means samples, do not confuse with umbraco templates) in Umbraco back office. At some point I need to send email using this template(subject, body, cc, bcc, etc). For that I use auto generated models, which require `IPublishedContent` for initalization.

So I cannot initialize this model as I cannot get content of type `IPUblishedContent`.

When I get it by Id everything works fine. But I do not want to rely on id as it changes and decided to use path and cannot do that. I get NullReferenceException when I execute following:

```
 contentCache.GetByRoute(true, "relative path to email template")//I think I am mistaken here as I am using cache
```

relative path looks like `"/settings/emailtemplate/registrationtemplate"` Can anyone point me how to achieve this as I am new to Umbraco and struggling to understand how should I do certain things.

---

Another approach which I tried initially(which is also not successful) is to get content by doc type id

```
 var contentService = umbracoContext.Application.Services.ContentService;
 var contentTypeService = umbracoContext.Application.Services.ContentTypeService;
 var contentType = contentTypeService.GetContentType("emailSettings");
 var templates = contentService.GetContentOfContentType(contentType.Id);
```

then I get content from ContentService:

```
 var content = templates.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name.Contains("Registration"));
 var publishedContent = contentService.GetById(content.Id)
```

But here I get `publishedContent` as `IContent` and there is no way to convert it to `IPublishedContent`.

---

**Update 1**

I found that the reason is that I am trying to get published content from Umbraco API controller. So the question is **Is there a way to get published content from api**?

Comment: What is your version of umbraco?

Comment: it is Umbraco 7.5.7

Comment: On the GetByRoute part, that's for getting a page by it's URL. If there isn't an umbraco page with the URL "/settings/emailtemplate/registrationtemplate" it won't return anything.

Does your email template have a corresponding Umbraco page, or iOS it just a standalone template?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You didn't mention Umbraco but you can use UmbracoHelper like this.

```
IPublishedContent content = UmbracoHelper.TypedContent(content.Id);
```

If you cant have access to UmbracoHelper take it like this:

```
var umbracoHelper = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);
```

Comment: unfortunately it did not fix the issue. Result of `UmbracoHelper.TypedContent(content.Id);` empty model.

Comment: If the Id is correct and the content node is in the umbraco published content cache then you will get the content - ut will only return null if the content is not there, so you either have the wrong id, or the content is not published